# Linux Kernel parameters which can be tuned when TCP backlog exceeds in WebSphere MQ server

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, ibm-mq, tcplistener, backlog

We are facing an issue where we see TCP backlogs gets exceeded than default value (100) on our MQ server (v7.5) running on Linux (Redhat) platform during high number of connection requests on MQ server. The ListenerBacklog is configured as 100 in qm.ini which is the default listener backlog value (maximum connection requests) for Linux. Whenever we have connections burst and TCP backlogs exceeds the queue manager stops functioning and resumes only when queue manager/server is restarted.

So we are looking whether there are attributes in Linux kernel related to socket tuning which can improve tcp backlog at network layer and cause no harm to queue manager.Does increasing these values as below in /etc/sysctl.conf will help to resolve this issue or improve performance of queue manager?

net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096

net.core.somaxconn = 1024

net.core.rmem_max = 16777216

net.core.wmem_max = 16777216

Comment: There's no reason for the queue manager to stop functioning under this condition. The client will get connection refusals or timeouts, but the server won't even know about that. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I agree with EJP. Suggest your pursue with IBM support as it sounds like the queue manager is not functioning correctly.